# LCD Flat Screen Gives Application Error Hardware Related?

Tags: vb6, screen, lcd, vga

Hi I have a vb6 application running 24 x 7 in a HP PC. I have connected a 42" LCD TV Screen to display information via VGA input in the Screen. The application controls vehicle entering and exiting the premises.

The Issue here is after running the application either 2 or 3 days or even 4 hours later (Time is immaterial). I get application error like "Null value not found!".

Where as if I unplug the LCD screen. and run the application. I do not have any issue. Can anyone explain where I am I going wrong please.

Thank you

Comment: It's going to be much more challenging to assist without seeing the code where the problem is occurring. Please [edit] it into your question.

Comment: Thank you for the comment peter, I thought as much, But If the issue is in the code why it is not coming up when I do not connect the LCD monitor?

Comment: That's just it, there's really no way for me to guess why without seeing the exact error message and the code being run (preferably a [mcve]). Maybe there's a bug with a certain resolution screen, or maybe it looks up the monitor model in some database that doesn't have it listed. There's not really anything we can do across the Internet to diagnose it based on the information you've given.

Comment: Yes Peter, I am also not sure how to diagnose this, I need to try and get a VGA to RCA converter to push the video signal out. I am not sure this will resolve the issue, Since I am using the normal motherboard VGA port my guess is weather VGA is ment for monitors? Having said that the LCD has a VGA input port.

Comment: There was a bug in older VB5-era controls that they would/could crash or malfunction on computers which had a touchscreen. I don't think any touch inputs were actually required to cause the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the comment Daveln. I heard yes vb5 has issues. But I am using vb6 and my monitor is not a touch screen. it is just to display the message